# If you have been

Tags: meaning, grammar

At the end of a youtube video, the presenter says "If you have been, thanks for watching"

I'm not sure about the first part, as i expect something after "have been"

does it mean "if you have been watching, thanks"?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.  And I suspect it's a bit of a joke, suggesting that many people have such Youtube pieces running without actually watching them.

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing the sentence or sentences that came before. The person could have said, 'Many people having been wanting to see my new beard. If you have been, thanks for watching." In which case, what they've been doing is wanting to see the person's new beard … (Without any additional context, it's reasonable to interpret it as you have. However, it's not a given.)

Comment: Thanks. The guy always ends his video with that sentence. So I think it would be correct to link up with "watching"